# Розовые текстуры спрайтов при сборке проекта Unity

Tags: unity3d, 2d

В редакторе и плей моде всё в порядке. При сборке проекта спрайты, которые включены в атлас, который включен в ассет-бандл addressable, отрисовываются розовыми. Я достаю эти спрайты в рантайме из бандла через AssertReference из базы данных спрайтов ScriptableObject. Проблема в шейдере, который их должен отрисовывать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Неужели никто не сталкивался с подобным поведением